# How to delete google map from android app?

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps

I have App Android and implements services in buid.grable (app):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.30.3
```

**I used Yandex map and include implements:**

> implementation 'com.yandex.android:maps.mobile:4.0.0-full'

After adding a Yandex map, my application became very large (> 99Mb).
I would like to reduce the size of the application by removing the google maps.

How to remove Google maps from Android App?

Comment: Yandex map and Google map are different things. Google map should be much smaller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540015/how-to-reduce-apk-apk-size-in-android-studio
This will help you to shrink apk size.